# Static provide method in Dagger2

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

Why should use static modifier before the provide method?

Even though I remove the static modifier, dagger2 works correctly.

```
@Provides static Pump providePump(Thermosiphon pump) {
    return pump;
}
```

Comment: I don't know. I think the docs are lying in this case, actually. How are you going to override a static provider method for the mocks? You can't. As such, adding `static` is honestly stupid, and the documentation makes zero sense for doing so. Although it's also known for its "coffee example" that doesn't actually tell you how to use the library, so it's no wonder it does other things that make no sense. /rant

Comment: Using static function for `@Provides` helps to reduce some generated codes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both styles work; whether you keep the method static is entirely up to you and your normal "should this be a static method" judgment in plain old Java. Here, `pump` doesn't have any use for a module instance, so the method can easily be static.

Static method calls are faster, [particularly in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic), because they avoid a virtual method table lookup. This may also make them easier for compilers, JIT runtimes, or static analysis tools to inline. I'd surmise you'd open up similar advantages by making the class or method `final`.

There may also be a slight improvement in readability given that a static method can't be subject to instance fields, but that's up to you.

If you are confident that your @Provides method's behavior is *not subject to change including in tests*, then you can take advantage of the performance/readability increase. However, if you need to refer to module state or want to allow subclass/testing overrides, then an instance method is necessarily the right call.

Comment: Thank you for providing the idea when to use and why to use. It's very clear. I will mark this as answer.

Comment: Hmm, they use static methods for tests in Dagger documentation https://google.github.io/dagger//testing.html See `@Provides static AuthManager authManager` at the bottom, is that a mistake on their part, or am I missing something?

Comment: @arekolek No mistake; that module is FakeAuthModule, used for testing but _never changed or overridden_ because it is a test-only Module per "Option 2: Separate component configurations". Non-final methods for testing are specifically to enable "Option 1: Override bindings by subclassing modules (don’t do this!)", with its headline caveat based on the limitations listed on that page. I don't disagree: Other than very fast or limited overrides (or Modules designed for overriding) you probably want a separate Component for tests with separate modules (and abstract or static `@Provides` methods).

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. They subclass the component and include different modules, but they don't subclass modules themselves.